# How to return a generator/map object from FastAPI endpoint (Python)?

Tags: python-3.x, rest, generator, fastapi, pydantic

I'm working on my first FastAPI and Pydantic project, came across a problem when trying to return a generator from an endpoint. The problem is below, any inputs will be really appreciated!

I have an API endpoint where I first get data records from a database, then format each record using a *map* function. However, when returning the mapped result to the endpoint, the key-value mapping went wrong. Note, I'd like to keep the return type from the endpoint as a generator for performance sake (big data volume).

My pseudo-code:

```
@app.get("/records", response_model=Iterable[RecordModel])
async def get_records() -> Iterable[RecordModel]:
    # {queried_records} is a generator returned from the database query
    queried_records = get_records_from_database() 
    formatted_records = map(lambda record: __format(record), queried_records)
    return formatted_records

async def __format(queried_record: Dict[str, Union[str, HttpUrl]) -> Union[RecordModel, None]:
    formatted_record = RecordModel(
        key_1 = queried_record[key_a],
        key_2 = queried_record[key_b],
        key_3 = queried_record[key_c]
    )
    return formatted_record
```

By this, I got an error when running the endpoint

```
ValueError: [ValueError('dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 3; 2 is required'), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]
```

---

if I change *__format* method to

```
async def __format(queried_record: Dict[str, Union[str, HttpUrl]) -> Union[RecordModel, None]:
    formatted_record = RecordModel(
        key_1 = queried_record[key_a],
        key_2 = queried_record[key_b]
    )
    return formatted_record
```

From Swagger UI, I could see the endpoint was executed to a response body of

```
{ key_1: key_2 }
```

Very strange, I spent quite a while debugging, but couldn't sort it out. How to fix the **ValueError** mentioned above? Big thanks for your inputs in advance!

Comment: when format is async you should await it or just remove async

Comment: swagger tels you what it will return because of `response_model=Iterable[RecordModel]` It does not mean that that is what you will actually return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tinkering for a while, though I still didn't solve the `ValueError` mentioned in the above post, I found a work-around - when dealing with the database big queries, using ***pagination*** for queries instead of returning generators as query results.

So improved and working pseudo-code:

```
@app.get("/records", response_model=List[RecordModel])
async def get_records(
    offset: int = 0, # start position of the query
    limit: int = 1000 # size of the query
) -> List[RecordModel]:
    queried_records = get_records_from_database(offset, limit) 
    formatted_records = map(lambda record: __format(record), queried_records)
    return list(formatted_records)

def __format(queried_record: Dict[str, Union[str, HttpUrl]) -> Union[RecordModel, None]:
    formatted_record = RecordModel(
        key_1 = queried_record[key_a],
        key_2 = queried_record[key_b],
        key_3 = queried_record[key_c]
    )
    return formatted_record
```

By this, I hand over to the API users the responsibility of handling big database queries by the use of pagination.

Answer (score 0):

- When format is async you should await it or just remove async
- Swagger (OpenAPI) tels you what it will return because of response_model=Iterable[RecordModel] It does not mean that that is what you will actually return
- You can use a list comprehension instead of `map`
- Regargin the response model `RecordModel` you can just start by removing it. and then the API wil return whatherver.

  - However then you will loose some of your documentation in Swagger
  - Another solution is to check if (and fix) the model actually fits what you return.

```
@app.get("/records")
async def get_records() -> Iterable[RecordModel]: return [
    __format(record) for record 
    in get_records_from_database()
]

def __format(
    queried_record: Dict[str, Union[str, HttpUrl]
) -> Union[RecordModel, None]: return RecordModel(
    key_1 = queried_record[key_a],
    key_2 = queried_record[key_b],
    key_3 = queried_record[key_c]
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the inputs @mama! :) 

I should remove async of *__format* method, true.


However, I'd return a generator from the API endpoint for performance reason, because it'll come with a big data volume.


Also need to keep *RecordModel* as the response model, so my API users can see from Swagger documentation.


Any idea on the *ValueError* mentioned in the post? Loads of thanks! :)